# How to connect Flask API endpoints to React app

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios, web-development-server

I have an API made on Flask that has several endpoints. I am trying to use data from these end points to display a chart on my front end that shows the data to the user.

The following are my exact requirements:

Implement one or more types of charts that can be used to effectively visualize data supplied from the API endpoints. Users should be able to pick different metrics to visualize and compare with others.

My Flask API:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, session, request
import sqlalchemy
import time
from functools import wraps

# web app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super_secure_key_that_should_be_in_.env'

# database engine
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(os.getenv('SQL_URI'))

def rate_limit(**limit_kwargs):
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            limit = limit_kwargs['limit'] if 'limit' in limit_kwargs else 5
            seconds = limit_kwargs['window'] if 'window' in limit_kwargs else 60
            session_key = 'rate_limit_' + str(request.url_rule)
            if session_key not in session:
                session[session_key] = []

            window: list = session[session_key]
            if len(window) < limit:
                window.append(int(time.time()))
                session[session_key] = window
                return function(*args, **kwargs)

            if time.time() - window[0] < seconds:
                return jsonify(error='Rate limit exceeded'), 429

            window.pop(0)
            window.append(int(time.time()))
            session[session_key] = window
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@app.route('/')
@rate_limit()
def index():
    return 'Welcome '


@app.route('/events/hourly')
@rate_limit(limit=3, window=20)
def events_hourly():
    return queryHelper('''
        SELECT date, hour, events
        FROM public.hourly_events
        ORDER BY date, hour
        LIMIT 168;
    ''')


@app.route('/events/daily')
@rate_limit(limit=2)
def events_daily():
    return queryHelper('''
        SELECT date, SUM(events) AS events
        FROM public.hourly_events
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date
        LIMIT 7;
    ''')


@app.route('/stats/hourly')
@rate_limit(limit=3, window=20)
def stats_hourly():
    return queryHelper('''
        SELECT date, hour, impressions, clicks, revenue
        FROM public.hourly_stats
        ORDER BY date, hour
        LIMIT 168;
    ''')


@app.route('/stats/daily')
@rate_limit(limit=2)
def stats_daily():
    return queryHelper('''
        SELECT date,
            SUM(impressions) AS impressions,
            SUM(clicks) AS clicks,
            SUM(revenue) AS revenue
        FROM public.hourly_stats
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date
        LIMIT 7;
    ''')

@app.route('/poi')
@rate_limit(limit=3)
def poi():
    return queryHelper('''
        SELECT *
        FROM public.poi;
    ''')

def queryHelper(query):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(query).fetchall()
        return jsonify([dict(row.items()) for row in result])
```

My React App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import DailyEvents from "./Components/DailyEvents";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className= "App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title"> Welcome to React</h1>
                </header>
                <DailyEvents />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

My Components/DailyEvents.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    dates: []
  }
    componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('api_url_or_localhost/events/daily')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ dates: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }
}

export default App;
```

I keep getting a TypeError that instance.render is not a function.

What I am trying to do is use my Flask API endpoints to visualize the data on the front-end.

Comment: Where is your react code?

Comment: I haven't really gotten much headway with react because I am unsure of how to start

Comment: A good place to start: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Answer (score 0):

try using axios  : 
https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/

it should look like this :

```js
axios.get('put the query address')
      .then(response => {
        process your response
      })
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just to clarify, the query address would be whats in @app.route() right?

Comment: whats inside @app.route is only the last bit of the url, you also need the base_url, which looks something like http://localhost:5000, or the address where you host your Flask API - http://localhost:5000/events/daily would be the full url if you run it on your machine

Answer (score 0):

Can / Should you make changes to the Flask API, or is that code part of the requirements? Because I'm pretty sure you won't be able to return those Date objects straight from the DB without serializing them first.

I suggest you use Postman (or just a browser, for get requests) to test the routes locally and basically have a look at the data first.
React can use Axios or fetch to get this data and visualize it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    dates: []
  }      
    componentDidMount() {
    fetch('api_url_or_localhost/events/daily'))
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ dates: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }
  ...
}
```

see this https://pusher.com/tutorials/consume-restful-api-react for more details